Sending image to webpage - how to change Python 2 code to Python 3?
For many years I have used a small Python2 script which sends thumbnails of images to a webpage.
A minimal working version is:
Webpage:
<img src="./sendthumb.cgi" />

Python2 script sendthumb.cgi:
#! /usr/bin/python

from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys

pic = "testpic.jpg"

im = Image.open(pic)
im.thumbnail((256, 256))
buf = StringIO()
im.save(buf, "JPEG")

sys.stdout.write('Status: 200 OK\r\n')
sys.stdout.write('Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n')
sys.stdout.write('\r\n')
sys.stdout.write(buf.getvalue())

However, my service providers are now switching off Python2, so it's time to amend the script to work with Python3. A bit of research suggests that I need to switch StringIO to BytesIO, and send to sys.stdout.buffer. So the new script is:
#! /usr/bin/python3

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import sys

pic = "testpic.jpg"

im = Image.open(pic)
im.thumbnail((256, 256))
buf = BytesIO()
im.save(buf, "JPEG")

sys.stdout.write('Status: 200 OK\r\n')
sys.stdout.write('Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n')
sys.stdout.write('\r\n')
sys.stdout.buffer.write(buf.getvalue())

This doesn't seem to trigger any errors - but it also doesn't display the image on the webpage. Could somebody point out how to correct this?

Maybe try adding flush=True to parameters of last line.

Or maybe it's sys.stdout.flush() as a new final line.

@MarkSetchell: Thank you for the suggestions. flush=True triggers an error; sys.stdout.flush() doesn't give an error but there's still no image displayed.

Try running your script in the Terminal like this ./sendthumb.cgi > junk and see if the file junk is 40-50 bytes longer than testpic.jpg - the additional bytes being the HTTP header you added.

@MarkSetchell Well of course it's much smaller, because it has been thumbnailed. But if I double-click on junk it opens in Image Viewer as a smaller copy of the original image.

@MarkSetchell However, poking about in junk with a hex viewer has pointed me to the solution - so thank you!

Cool - well done! And thanks for sharing the answer.

To answer my own question, in case it helps others.
The solution is to send all the output to sys.stdout.buffer:
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'Status: 200 OK\r\n')
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n')
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\r\n')
sys.stdout.buffer.write(buf.getvalue())

